# Getting a query result taken from the same data but with temporary var

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got a simple thing to do.
Well, maybe not, but someone somewhere surely can help me out  : P

I got a simple data structure that contains

- expedition date
- delivery date
- transaction type

I would need to create a query which could 
order the rows by a date specific to the transaction type.

(ie : using the expedition date for transaction of type "selling", and delivery date for transaction of type "purchasing")

**I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this than 
by fetching 2 times the same data with different clause where(while adding a column used to order them(tempDate)) and then using another select to encompass these 2 queries to which I would add the order clause on the tempDate.**

**--> the initial fetching I would do 2 times works on many tables(many, many, many joins)**

Basically my current solution is :

```
Select * from 

(

  Select ...

  date_exp as dateTemp;

  from ...

  where conditions* And dateRelatedCondition

  UNION

  Select ...

  date_livraison as dateTemp;

  from ...

  Where conditions* And NOT(dateRelatedCondition)

) as comboSelect

Order By MIN(comboSelect.dateTemp)
OVER(PARTITION BY(REF_product)), 
(REF_product), 
comboSelect.dateTemp asc;
```

*
->Those conditions are the same in both inner Select query

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Without the UNION:
  dateRelatedCondition should be removed from WHERE and put to the SELECT like:

```sql
CASE WHEN dateRelatedCondition THEN date_exp ELSE date_livraison END as dateTemp
```

- Without the subquery:
  in ORDER BY you need the same expression in the window function:

```sql
Order By MIN(CASE WHEN dateRelatedCondition THEN date_exp ELSE date_livraison END)  
OVER(PARTITION BY(REF_product)), 
(REF_product),
dateTemp asc
```

Comment: There are some data I've not given.

The query ending is 

ORDER BY Min(tempDate)

OVER(PARTITION BY( rowRef_Id )), 
rowRef_Id, 
tempDate asc;

Comment: OK, I update my answer with your expression from the question.

Comment: Can't seem to access the dateTemp variable in the Order By clause.
Invalid Column Name.

Comment: You might still need to do a subquery first with the CASE expression and only then do the ordering in the outer query. Or put the CASE expression in place of the dateTemp - but this one won't look very nice and could be hard to be revised later.

Comment: Had to keep the first Select clause to be able to use the "comboSelect" to get to the variable for it to work.   

So something like 

Select ... from ( Select  )) as comboSelect 
Order By ...

Got a better solution ?

Comment: Try without comboSelect by putting the CASE expression in place of the dateTemp Order By MIN(CASE ...)

Comment: But first I would re-design the ORDER BY: why not just dateTemp, REF_product ?

Comment: because it enables me to group the data related to a specific ref_product together

Comment: For the Order By MIN(CASE.. )

I will still need the last dateTemp for the ordering the rows inside the blocs of data created by the OVER PARTITION

and the MIN( )  dont accept the "as dateTemp"

Comment: What is the best query form performance wise ?

Is the query with one select and 2x the Case instruction better for uses on a large set of rows ? 1000+  than the query with a subQuery( select (select) as comboSelect)   ?

Comment: You need to test the run times and compare the query plans

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?:

```
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN TransactionType = 'Selling' THEN ExpeditionDate
  WHEN TransactionType = 'purchasing' THEN DeliveryDate
END
```

Comment: Sorry, had forgot to add some of the Order by clause...
Didn't think it would matter.

I will need the variable dateTemp to order the rows at the end

Comment: Ok, so after the code in my answer, add `, dateTemp`.   If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Works only if I end the Order By clause like this

ORDER BY MIN(
CASE
  WHEN TransactionType = 'Selling' THEN ExpeditionDate
  WHEN TransactionType = 'purchasing' THEN DeliveryDate
END)
OVER(PARTITION BY(REF_product)), 
(REF_product), 
CASE
  WHEN TransactionType = 'Selling' THEN ExpeditionDate
  WHEN TransactionType = 'purchasing' THEN DeliveryDate
END asc.